# Strange bug in LUP Decomposition

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, code

I have written LU decomposition with partial pivot, but for some matrices, the entry `L[[1,1]]` isn't equal to `1` like it should be, throwing off the entire decomposition. Any ideas what is causing this?

(* LU DECOMP w/ pivot *)

```
Clear[U, L, A, j, k, a, b]
lupdecomp[A_?MatrixQ] := 
  Module[{P, max, index, x, i, n, y, dim, d, temp, j, k, a, U, L},
   dim = Dimensions[A];
   n = Length[A];
   U = A;
   L = IdentityMatrix[n];
   P = IdentityMatrix[n];

   For[k = 1, k < n, k++,
    max = Max[U[[k ;;, k]]];
    index = Flatten[Position[U[[k ;;, k]], max]][[1]];
    U[[{k, index}]] = U[[{index, k}]];
    L[[{k, index}, 1 ;; k - 1]] = L[[{index, k}, 1 ;; k - 1]];
    P[[{k, index}]] = P[[{index, k}]];
    For[j = k + 1, j <=  n, j++,
     L[[j, k]] = U[[j, k]]/U[[k, k]];
     For[a = k, a <= n, a++,
      U[[j, a]] = U[[j, a]] - L[[j, k]]*U[[k, a]];
           ];

          ];
    ];
   Return[{P, L, U}];
   ];
```

For example,

> b= {{4.40669, 3.43566, 9.61987}, {3.13933, 7.78681, 8.60175}, {9.29858, 
>    4.73565, 3.41126}}

Yields

> {P,L,U}={{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}, {{0.337614, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 
>     0}, {0.47391, 0.251578, 1}}, {{4.44089*^(-16), 6.18799, 
>     7.45006}, {9.29858, 4.73565, 3.41126}, {0., 0., 7.14504}}}

Which has an entry `L[[1,1]]` not equal to 1. However, for other matrices, such as

> b= {{7.01497, 9.75886, 4.12399}, {3.91071, 2.29947, 6.53455}, {8.28621, 
>    7.69486, 1.44275}}
>
> {P,L,U}={{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0.471954, 1, 
>     0}, {0.846584, -2.43555, 1}}, {{8.28621, 7.69486, 
>     1.44275}, {0., -1.33215, 5.85364}, {-8.88178*^(-16), 0.,
>      17.1594}}}

Which is a proper decomposition, as `LU=Pb`

Any ideas what I"m doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in these two lines:

```
max = Max[U[[k ;;, k]]];
index = Flatten[Position[U[[k ;;, k]], max]][[1]];
```

You are looking for the pivoting row, so you have to add `k-1` to index. In fact, you can have this easier by loading `` Needs["LinearAlgebra`BLAS`"] `` and by using

```
index = IAMAX[U[[k ;;, k]]] + (k - 1);
```

instead.

Here is also a somewhat more optimized version of the algorithm. It (i) gets rid of two `For` loops in favor of fast matrix operations and (ii) ensures that packed arrays are used if `A` is a matrix of machine precision reals.

```
Needs["LinearAlgebra`BLAS`"]

lupdecomp[A_?MatrixQ] := Module[{n, P, U, L, index, k},
   n = Length[A];
   U = Developer`ToPackedArray[A];
   L = IdentityMatrix[n, WorkingPrecision -> Precision[A]];
   P = IdentityMatrix[n, WorkingPrecision -> Precision[A]];
   Do[
    index = IAMAX[U[[k ;;, k]]] + (k - 1);
    U[[{k, index}]] = U[[{index, k}]];
    L[[{k, index}, 1 ;; k - 1]] = L[[{index, k}, 1 ;; k - 1]];
    P[[{k, index}]] = P[[{index, k}]];
    L[[k + 1 ;;, k]] = U[[k + 1 ;;, k]]/U[[k, k]];
    U[[k + 1 ;;, k ;;]] = U[[k + 1 ;;, k ;;]] - KroneckerProduct[L[[k + 1 ;;, k]], U[[k, k ;;]]];
    , {k, 1, n}];
   {P, L, U}
   ];
```

Here is a test:

```
n = 15;
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
{P, L, U} = lupdecomp[A];
Max[Abs[P\[Transpose].L.U - A]]
```

> 4.44089*10^-16

Comment: This is because 1) we start the indexing with `1` and 2) we are finding the position of the max element in terms of numbers after `k`, so to get the index from the start of the matrix, we have to add `(k-1)`. If the indexing started at `0`, we would add `k`, correct?

Comment: Right. If you _could_ start indexing with `0` which you cannot in _Mathematica_.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of "If i had to write this in c++, it'd be `+k` and not `+(k-1)`". If i remember correctly C++ indexing begins with `0`. I can't believe I didn't spot that, thanks as always @Henrik!

Comment: You're welcome.